# building a mysql query dynamically in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

We have a use case where users have access to certain fields in a record.
For example, take a customer record. A user could have access to see the customers first and last name, but not their phone or email.

sample record:

```
id, company, first_name, last_name, email, phone
'3', 'ABC Company', 'Kevins', kevinboy@gmail.com, 667-545-9502
```

We're tying to build a query dynamically so that depending on what permissions a user has, they can edit only the fields for a record that they are permissioned to on a front-end dashboard.

The assumption is that if a user has view permissions to see certain fields of the record, they would also have the capability to edit those fields. Yes, a field has add, view, edit, and delete settings for each user. A user can not add a new record unless they have add permission on that field, can't edit unless they have edit permission on the field, and same with view and delete.

We are facing issues with the best approach to building a query dynamically to allow for an edit on the fly. For example, we have a working concept:

```
permissions = engine.execute("SELECT column_name from user_profile where id = 1 and table_name = 'cust' and `edit` = 1")
formatted_query = "UPDATE cust SET %s WHERE id = %s" % (",".join([column_name[0] + ' = %s' for column_name in permissions]), request.json.get('id'))
values = tuple([request.json.get(column_name[0]) for column_name in permissions])
engine.execute(formatted_query, values)
```

In this way, when a request is sent to our endpoint, we check the fields that the user has edit permissions for on the customers table. Then we build the SQL query dynamically, selecting the proper column names, and values that would be passed in from the API call.

Sample api payload would be like: POST /edituser `{"cust_id": 15, "first_name": "johnson", "last_name": "doe"}`
In the permissions variable, id of 1 is the user who is actually making the api call, so we check their permissions.

Any suggestions to make this perform better?

Update:
Dynamically created using SQLALCHEMY:

```
engine.execute(table('cust').update().values({text(key): request.json.get(key) for key in [column_name[0] for column_name in permissions]}).where(column('id') == request.json.get('id')))
```

Comment: could you show an example of how this is open to injection?

Comment: on a select statement that doesn't take parameters from a user, it should be fine to format the query using string formatting or no, it would not be okay in that situation too? Thanks ill check that out @roganjosh

Comment: @roganjosh but can the actual SQL update query be created dynamically using string formatting, and then using binding to properly join the fields? In my example, I am using string formatting both to to build the query (no user input), and then to get user input. I cant find a way to dynamically build the query with the proper update fields using parameterization

Comment: Actually, hold on. I was looking on my phone. You are actually doing what I suggested. Ignore me!

Comment: The only thing I can suggest here, having had another look, is that you could be using a `ForeignKey` on the user id so you wouldn't need to be updating other tables on a change. This is part of database normalisation (look into 3NF)

Comment: @roganjosh the customers table has its own primary key (id), so I didn't quite follow you by usinga  foreign key, I'm not updating any other tables besides customers in this scenario. Also can you check my updated question. At the bottom I include the parameterized dynamic query + values using SQLALCHEMY formatting.